# Use case for async IO when dealing with one socket and multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, networking, boost-asio

I'm struggling to see why some programmers recommend asynchronous IO when there is only one socket, like the common case of UDP. This is more directed at ASIO which is the basis of what we will be getting in C++17 but applies generally to any async library.

Is there a use case where it makes sense? I can't see how the performance would ever be better than two threads, one blocking on read (then queueing packets for a threadpool) and one blocking on write with a conditional variable waiting for packets to send. Preferably using the multipacket functions there to avoid operating system overhead.

Is there anything in the pipeline to help the efficiency of UDP or single socket TCP in ASIO? Pretty much all the ASIO examples show synchronous reading and writing. ie you only do another read or write in the handler for the last one. So there is very little benefit gained per socket, certainly nothing that can be better than dedicated recv and write threads for those examples if dealing with only one socket.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Unfortunately, many ASIO implementations do have umm.. 'issues'. Making more system calls than a simple blocking design, while not allowing multiple IO requests to be queued in the kernel, is one :(

Comment: It's actually quite funny, reading questions like 'I use non-blocking ASIO for high purrformance, how can I wait for the result?'

Comment: I saw that some people say it is possible to queue multiple reads or writes but it depends on the operating system, and some of them can even return less than you want which makes the use nearly pointless (weirdly interleaved packets). In a one thread for read and write situation that would never happen. Either way I cannot see how that could ever be faster for a single socket than the situation I describe.

Comment: Few use cases from my personal experience: single core small-form factor where context switching was costly; memory constrained environments where it was ideal to handle flow control in the network stack instead of the application; protocols where latency was not critical, and multithreading complexity did not outweigh potential gains. Asio is designed for [portability, scalability, and efficiency](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/rationale.html). As a consequence of its design, I accept that some performance will be sacrificed in specific scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, ASIO might yield worse performance than multithreading. With true multithreading and multiple cores (stndard nowadays) you will have the chance of serving two clients at exactly the same time (this will never happen with a single-threaded ASIO model). However, if, for instance, your tasks are IO-bound, use common resource with synchronized access (single-threaded DB, for instance) or are subject to any other locks, any benefit of multithreading will vanish.

From the other hand, ASIO model is much simpler, doesn't require any synchronization, allows one to compile the program in single-threaded mode (thus, for example, increasing performance of memory allocations, eliminating need for atomic access, etc). In many scenarios those benefits outweight the drawbacks.

Comment: "ASIO model is much simpler" This is not necessarily true because normal sequential code gets turned into callbacks. Control flow turned into callbacks is quite nasty.

Comment: @usr, simpler is subjective. I find it simpler :), but may be because I have a long experience with it.

Comment: A single thread for read and write is a lot less code and much cleaner to read than the cluster of weird ASIO calls, on top of being way more performant. I don't mind the extra complexity ASIO (or IOCP/whatever) adds if you only have to write it once and it works and is using the fastest methods on each OS. It seems that in many cases ASIO isn't using the fastest methods and in some use cases it is very unoptimized. It feels like it was written to handle a HTTP server and everything else was just tacked on at the end. UDP in particular seems poorly handled compared to other libraries.

Comment: @SergeyA I don't understand what you mean when you say it doesn't require synchronization. If you use multiple threads and more than one socket you need to. I'm not sure anyone who writes software these days should ever use a single thread unless they are on embedded systems. Every opportunity you can use to make your application feel smoother and scale better should be taken especially when its nearly the same amount of effort, just my 2 cents.

Comment: @RylerSturden, there are some successful single-threaded systems. Certainly have their usage. NodeJs is one of them.

Comment: I'm not saying you can't make successful single threaded software. However from what I know nodejs isn't single threaded, some aspects of it are but it as a whole is not so I'm not sure why you are using it as an example in regards to my comment. I am just stating you should multithread nearly all software if you want the best experience and nodeJS does that as it should.

Comment: NodeJS gives a single threaded model based on async IO. Or any JavaScript program for that matter - they are all async io single-threaded. There are apps (or subsystems of apps) which are inherently single-threaded because of business logic. I'd give you examples, but it really seems you are asking a question while already knowing your answer, so I do not see any point in further discussion.

Comment: NodeJS is a red herring, I think you can't learn much from it for this question. It's single-threaded event loop is forced by the JavaScript language. It's not a good thing. NodeJS has no inherent perf advantages whatsoever that cannot be emulated in any other language that has decent async IO support.

Comment: @usr, I was only invoking NodeJS as an example of successfull single-threaded app (in a response to ' I'm not sure anyone who writes software these days should ever use a single thread unless they are on embedded systems."). Performance-wise NodeJS is far from being perfect, I know of people who are weaning of it exactly for performance reasons.

Comment: @SergeyA I think there may be a miscommunication here because the NodeJS (the server) is not single threaded. Are you talking about nodeJS based apps? If nodeJS was single threaded it would perform extremely poorly. I think you are confusing the end app being "singlethreaded" and calling that nodeJS. Or maybe I am confused. I don't know. :)

Comment: @RylerSturden, you are missing the point. NodeJS is a framework. It can be anything. But the application you run within this netwokr is single-threaded. Imagine you write a single-threaded application in Java. Even if Java machine itself is multithreaded (it always is), the application is single-threaded. Same thing with NodeJS applications.

Comment: No I am not missing the point I don't think sergey. The only reason NodeJS is so performant is the fact it uses multiple cores. The fact it can hide that for the end user of a nodejs app just makes it good software.

Comment: @RylerSturden, yes, you are missing it. A NodeJS appplication is a single-threaded, async-IO based application.

Comment: Yes but the server that is hosting that app is not single threaded. If the server was single threaded the async IO based application would suck in performance.

Comment: @RylerSturden, last time I repeat it. I do not care about the server framework. The application is a single threaded thing. The framework can do whatever it wants.

Comment: @SergeyA I understand that. But pretending that the power of NodeJS has nothing to do with it leveraging multiple cores is pretty silly. Please reread your comments.